# Monodevelop + NAudio on Ubuntu linux tells me "Expression denotes a type where method group

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, monodevelop, naudio

I have already referenced NAudio library in my project how ever when i run my code it tells me something along the lines of "Expression denotes a `type`, where a `method group` was expected.

Here is my code and the error is at the line of `waveFile = WaveFileReader("somefile.wav");`

```
using System;
using Gst;
using GLib;
using Gst.BasePlugins;

using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;


namespace record_audio_simple_test
{


    class MainClass
    {

        //Define class variables
        private NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader waveFile = null;
        private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            waveFile = WaveFileReader("somefile.wav");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using MonoDevelop, Ubuntu Linux, and NAudio, my target hardware is an embedded linux box but first I need to make it work before I try to port it to the embedded box I'm using NAudio becuase I assume that it will be cross-compatible as long as their are supported codecs installed on the target system(Like Gstreamer or w/e).

Comment: are you missing the new keyword ? waveFile = new WaveFileReader("somefile.wav");

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! Its difficult to know how to initialize things right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your code are you sure its not soposed to look like this?:

```
 WaveFileReader waveFile = new WaveFileReader("somefile.wav");
```

Correct me if I am wrong. Hope I helped if i'm not wrong.

Comment: I declare it in the line of
    private NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader waveFile = null;

Although I tried your solution any ways (just to see if a different result would appear) and still the exact same error. I appreciate you taking the time to take a look at it however, thanks.

Comment: I will look over at this and get back to you ASAP

Comment: Oh wow I didn't see that you put "new" in there I need to audit suggestions even more carefully than I once thought I was doing, I appreciate it mate thank you!